# Where can I find C++/C code for tree isomorphism problem?

Tags: c++, tree, isomorphism

Where can I find code for tree isomorphism problem in O(N), where N is the number of nodes?

Comment: I am not sure If such algorithm exists. I am writing my final university project on this topic, I have to compare some of these algorithms but neither of them is O(n), all of them run in at least O(n logn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one such link: http://www.mareksacha.com/blog/tree-isomorphism-implementation

4th result on Google for *"tree isomorphism c++"*